# QML unit testing: running qmltestrunner

Tags: ubuntu-touch, application-development, qt, ubuntu-sdk, qml

I'm on ubuntu 14.04. I installed the Ubuntu SDK IDE. Running a QML App on my Ubuntu phone via the IDE works fine.
I'm following this tutorial on testing https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/apps/qml/tutorials/qml-unit-testing/.
Here's my error message:

```
qmltestrunner -input tests/unit
qmltestrunner: could not exec '/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt4/bin/qmltestrunner': No such file or directory
```

I assume that my bash tries to use the Qt version included in the python distribution anaconda.

```
which qmltestrunner 
/usr/bin/qmltestrunner

qmake -v
QMake version 2.01a
Using Qt version 4.8.7 in /home/user/anaconda/lib
```

I have several Qt versions installed:

```
qtchooser -list-versions
4
5
default
qt4-i386-linux-gnu
qt4
qt5-i386-linux-gnu
qt5
```

I want the bash to execute a Qt version, which runs qmltestrunner.

The file qmltestrunner exists in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/bin.  I tried to run it:

```
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmltestrunner -input tests/unit
file:///home/user/ubuntuSDKprojects/CurrencyConverter/app/tests/unit/tst_main.qml:1:1: module "QtQuick" version 2.4 is not installed 
     import QtQuick 2.4 
     ^ 
********* Start testing of qmltestrunner *********
Config: Using QtTest library 5.2.1, Qt 5.2.1
QWARN  : qmltestrunner::tst_main::compile() 
  /home/user/ubuntuSDKprojects/CurrencyConverter/app/tests/unit/tst_main.qml produced 1 error(s):
    /home/user/ubuntuSDKprojects/CurrencyConverter/app/tests/unit/tst_main.qml:1,1: module "QtQuick" version 2.4 is not installed
  Working directory: /home/user/ubuntuSDKprojects/CurrencyConverter/app
  View: QQuickView, import paths:
    '/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/bin'
    '/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/qml'
  Plugin paths:
    '.'

FAIL!  : qmltestrunner::tst_main::compile() module "QtQuick" version 2.4 is not installed
   Loc: [/home/user/ubuntuSDKprojects/CurrencyConverter/app/tests/unit/tst_main.qml(1)]
Totals: 0 passed, 1 failed, 0 skipped
********* Finished testing of qmltestrunner *********
```

Is the Qt Version which can run qmltestrunner included in the Ubuntu SDK IDE? If so, where do I find it? If not, how can I add "QtQuick" version 2.4 to my qt5 in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/ ?